# matlab webfigure in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, matlab-figure

I am new to Spring MVC. I would like to display Matlab WebFigure on my web. I use Matlab javabuilder to deploy my program into java class. Java class returns Webfigure. In the Controller of my web project I would like to add WebFiggure html string into a model. Then i would like to display it:

```
Object[] result = transformace.transformace(4);
MWJavaObjectRef ref;

ref = (MWJavaObjectRef)result[0];
obrazek = (WebFigure)ref.get();

webFigures = new WebFigures("WebFigures",getServletContext());
String webFig = webFigures.getHtmlEmbedString(obrazek,"obrazek", "session", "", "", "");
model.addObject("webFig", webFig);
```

In the HelloWorldPage.jsp i like to get the figure and dislay it:

```
${webFig}
```

However when referencing webFig on *.jsp page I get an error:

```
Spring MVC Hello World Example

hello world mod2
HTTP Status 404 - /spring2-mvc-xml-hello-world/WebFigures/interface

type Status report

message /spring2-mvc-xml-hello-world/WebFigures/interface

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.48
```

Can You help me please?

sources:
HelloWorldPage.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="wf" uri="http://www.mathworks.com/builderja/webfigures.tld" %>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Spring MVC Hello World Example</h1>

    <h2>${msg} mod2</h2>
        <p>

        ${webFig}
        </p>
</body>
</html>
```

HelloWorldController.java

```
package com.mkyong.common.controller;

import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWJavaObjectRef;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFigure;
import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFigures;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;
import transformace.Transformace;

public class HelloWorldController extends AbstractController {


    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

                Transformace transformace;

                HttpSession session = request.getSession();            

                WebFigure obrazek= (WebFigure)session.getAttribute("obrazek");
                WebFigure obrazek1 = (WebFigure)session.getAttribute("obrazek1");
                WebFigure obrazek2=(WebFigure)session.getAttribute("obrazek2");
                WebFigure obrazek3=(WebFigure)session.getAttribute("obrazek3");

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HelloWorldPage");

                transformace = new Transformace();


                Object[] result = transformace.transformace(4);
                MWJavaObjectRef ref;

                ref = (MWJavaObjectRef)result[0];
                /* Z reference získáme data metodou get a uložíme je do webfigury. */
                obrazek = (WebFigure)ref.get();
                /* Nakonec nastavíme HttpSession. */
                session.setAttribute("obrazek", obrazek);
                ref = (MWJavaObjectRef)result[1];
                obrazek1 = (WebFigure)ref.get();
                session.setAttribute("obrazek1", obrazek1);
                ref = (MWJavaObjectRef)result[2];
                obrazek2 = (WebFigure)ref.get();
                session.setAttribute("obrazek2", obrazek2);
                ref = (MWJavaObjectRef)result[3];
                obrazek3 = (WebFigure)ref.get();
                session.setAttribute("obrazek3", obrazek3);     

                WebFigures webFigures;
                webFigures = new WebFigures("WebFigures",getServletContext());

                model.addObject("obr0", obrazek);
                model.addObject("obr1", obrazek1);
                model.addObject("obr2", obrazek2);
                model.addObject("obr3", obrazek3);

                String webFig = webFigures.getHtmlEmbedString(obrazek,"obrazek", "session", "", "", "");

                model.addObject("webFig", webFig);

        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

        return model;
    }

}
```

webfigures.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN"  "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">
<taglib>
<tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
<jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
<shortname>WebFigures</shortname>
<info>MATLAB Builder for Java WebFigures Tag library</info>
<tag>
<name>web-figure</name>
<tagclass>com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.JspWebFigureTag</tagclass>
<!--Body content can have a value of
empty: no body
JSP: body that is evaluated by container, then possibly
processed by the tag
tagdependent: body is only processed by tag; JSP in body is not
evaluated.
-->
<bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
<info>Embeds a live figure frame in an HTML document.</info>
<attribute>
<name>root</name>
<required>true</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>width</name>
<required>false</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>height</name>
<required>false</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>style</name>
<required>false</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>name</name>
<required>true</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
<attribute>
<name>scope</name>
<required>true</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/welcome.htm" 
        class="com.mkyong.common.controller.HelloWorldController" />

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring2-mvc-xml-hello-world</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring 2 MVC</name>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>2.5.6</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>test</groupId>
      <artifactId>test123</artifactId>
      <version>123</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
          <optional>true</optional>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>transformace2</groupId>
      <artifactId>transformace21</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/spring2</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <wtpContextName>spring2</wtpContextName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Go find an example of a Spring server serving a file, change the file and done. You really don't need to talk about matlab here at all it's not relevant.

Comment: Thx for comment. I edited the post. I forgot to mention that I use Matlab Javabuilder to create class from Matlab program. Matlab programreturns Webfigure. Using Webfigure function getHtmlEmbedString I should then get a string, which will somehow be displayed as Matlab Figure on the web page. However this is not working when I add it to the model and then call it from *.jsp page to display it... Do You know why is it not working? Thx a lot

Comment: Like I said go find an example somewhere. Looks like you found one from mkyong... So I don't see any problem in you looking for another. My advice would be to find one using SpringBoot, XML in Spring is dead. You can return a string HTML using @ResponseBody. Still you are talking about Matlab, please focus on your problem at hand when posting a question. Not just here is what I am doing make it work. If you do that more than likely you will see a relevant question on the right hand side with the answer you seek. You are cluttering SO otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this!

There were these entries missing in web.xml

```
    <servlet>         
        <servlet-name>WebFigures</servlet-name>         
        <servlet-class>com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFiguresServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet> 

     <servlet-mapping>         
         <servlet-name>WebFigures</servlet-name>         
         <url-pattern>/WebFigures/*</url-pattern>     
     </servlet-mapping>
```

I spend hours to solve this, hopefully this helps anybody dealing with the same problem!

complete web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet>         
        <servlet-name>WebFigures</servlet-name>         
        <servlet-class>com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.webfigures.WebFiguresServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet> 


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

     <servlet-mapping>         
         <servlet-name>WebFigures</servlet-name>         
         <url-pattern>/WebFigures/*</url-pattern>     
     </servlet-mapping>
```